# How to read content of text file as Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text-files, eslint, filereader, textreader

I want to write a function in **javascript** that reads text file and if it contains any javascript function in that text file then instead of reading it just as text, my function will **read** it as javascript.

Like:

```
const toBeRead = () => true; //This function is in text file
```

Above function is in text file and I want to read it as javascript. Currently I am reading this as a **string** but wanted to take output from it which is **true**.

Editing for better demonstration. Here is my function after using **eval()**

```
 function readSingleFile(evt) {
  var f = evt.target.files[0];
  if (f) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function (e) {
      var contents = e.target.result;
      var ct = r.result;
      var words = ct.split("\n");
      let array = [];
      words.map((word) => {
        if (word.substring(0, 6) === "const ") {
          if (word.includes("=>")) {
            if (word.includes("=")) {
              alert(word);       //It shows const toBeRead=()=>true;
              alert(eval(word)); // It shows undefined
              array.push(word);
            }
          }
        }
        return array;
      });
      alert(array);
    };
    r.readAsText(f);
  } else {
    alert("Failed to load file");
  }
}
```

Actually I am creating a rule for coding convention like if functions return boolean then it should start with "is/has". Like const isFuncTrue=()=>true; Don't have rule defined in Eslint!

Comment: Are you looking for [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Comment: I have used eval() but still not getting return from function defined in text file. I am reading text file line by line as it may contains more functions.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your attempt and indicate specifically how it's not working?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What's the big picture?  Is this an XY problem?  Why do you have JavaScript in a text file?  Is this node.js or browser or something else?

Comment: That's because `eval('x = 5')` --> 5.  but `eval('const x = 5')` --> undefined.

Comment: @David I want return value from function in my text file. By doing alert(eval(function)); it shows undefined in alert() where function value is "const abc=()=>true;"

Comment: @SulemanAhmad: In that example where do you define/assign `function`?  A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Wyck Do I have to split the function with the const in case there is arrow function defined in text file?

Comment: `eval('const x = 5')` is not an expression that evaluates to `5`.  it evaluates to `undefined`.  After `eval('const x = 5')`  a subsequent `eval('x')` won't even evaluate to `5`

Comment: Your premise that "output from it is true" is false.  The output of `const toBeRead = () => true` is undefined.  It does, however, introduce a constant called `toBeRead`.  If you appended the text `; return toBeRead` Then you might have a chance of eval returning the function object, but it still won't return `true`.  You're gravely mistaken about how JavaScript works and your expectations are inconsistent with how the language actually performs.

Comment: @David There is a map() used to parse line by line in my javascript function and I have that logic defined in my javascript function. I did console the value and function contains arrow function. I just want to get return from it and by using eval() alert is showing undefined!

Comment: @David Edit the post for you!

Comment: Can you just trim off the `const` part?  `theValue = eval(word.replace(/^const/,'')`

Comment: Can we see an example (multiple lines) of what's in the text file?  Do different lines depend on each other or anything else external?

Comment: @Wyck for the moment there is only one line in text file on which I am testing. Later on work with multiple ones.

Comment: I still have no idea why you're going about it this way.  You're way off track.  This is not the way JavaScript is to be used.  Why are you parsing JavaScript line at a time like this?

Comment: @Wyck to detect if there is any arrow function defined in text file if yes, then get return value from it.

Comment: You told me *what* you wanted to do, but did not tell me*why*.
 Maybe you want [esprima](https://esprima.org/) To parse the file and then see if any arrow functions were parsed.

Comment: Actually I am creating a rule for coding convention like if functions return true then it should start with "is/has". Like const isFuncTrue=()=>true; Dont have rule defined in Eslint!

Answer (score 3):

Two methods

1. `eval(jsstr)` - not recommended
2. script:

Example in browser - will not run if no DOM

```js
const str = `const toBeRead = () => true; //This function is in text file`
const scr = document.createElement("script")
scr.textContent = str;
document.body.appendChild(scr)
console.log(toBeRead())
```

Comment: Working with DOM but not in my case :(

Comment: JSDom.js perhaps?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe that's the problem. Is there any other way if we get the function (toBeRead) name as a string/text too after trimming it from real arrow function?